# Cuba Platform - All screens are disappeared in cuba-platform app

Tags: cuba-platform

I created a user and then logining for this user, all screens are disappeared. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only assumption I can make is that you use CUBA 7.2+ and your user has only the `system-minimal` role, thus their can only log in to the client without access to screens, entities, menu items, etc. I'd recommend defining a new role with the required permissions either design-time or run-time. See the Roles [documentation](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/roles.html) for more details.

Also, take a look at the [Security Subsystem](https://files.cuba-platform.com/cuba/release-notes/7.2/#security) section in the Release Notes to get familiar with changes made in CUBA 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please set up the security properly. It means you need to create a role either in your code in [design-time](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/roles.html#roles_design_time) or define a role for the new user in [runtime](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/roles.html#roles_run_time) and grant corresponding properties.

Note that permissions in CUBA follow the "allowing" principle. E.g. if you define an entity as read-only for one role and give full access in another one, then a user granted with both roles will get full access to the entity.